# How do I get git whatchanged to show a combined list of files that have changed?

Tags: git

I ran the following comand

```
git whatchanged 7c8358e.. --oneline
```

and got the below output. Is there a way to generate a *single* combined list of files that changed across all commits? In other words, I don't want files to show up more than once in the below list. Thanks!

```
4545ed7 refs #2911. error on 'caregivers_sorted_by_position' resolved in this update. it came up randomly in cucumber
:100644 100644 d750be7... 11a0bd0... M  app/controllers/reporting_controller.rb
:100644 100644 7334d4d... e43d9e6... M  app/models/user.rb
e9b2748 refs #2911. group dropdown filters the list to only the users that belong to the selected group
:100644 100644 fc81b9a... d750be7... M  app/controllers/reporting_controller.rb
:100644 100644 aaf2398... f19038e... M  app/models/group.rb
:100644 100644 3cc3635... 7a6b2b1... M  app/views/reporting/users.html.erb
48149c9 refs #2888 cherry pick 2888 from master into prod-temp
:100644 100644 3663ecc... f672b62... M  app/controllers/user_admin_controller.rb
:100644 100644 aaf2398... 056ea36... M  app/models/group.rb
:100644 100644 32363ef... bc9a1f2... M  app/models/role.rb
:100644 100644 91283fa... 7334d4d... M  app/models/user.rb
:100644 100644 d6393a0... bae1bd6... M  app/views/user_admin/roles.html.erb
994550d refs #2890. all requirements included. cucumber has 1 exception in bundle_job for count of data rows. everything else green
:100644 100644 145122d... 869a005... M  app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb
:100644 100644 f1bfa77... 2ed0850... M  app/views/alerts/message.html.erb
:100644 100644 e9f8a34... f358a74... M  app/views/call_list/_item.html.erb
:100644 000000 fda1297... 0000000... D  app/views/call_list/_load_caregivers.erb
:000000 100644 0000000... fda1297... A  app/views/call_list/_load_caregivers.html.erb
:100644 100644 168de9e... 43594f4... M  app/views/call_list/show.html.erb
:100644 100644 e178d7f... 0fe77e1... M  app/views/profiles/edit_caregiver_profile.html.erb
7396ff6 refs #2890. fixed --we're sorry-- error
:100644 100644 d55d46d... fc81b9a... M  app/controllers/reporting_controller.rb
7c8358e refs #2897 link on online store back to http://www.halomonitoring.com
:100644 100644 d6f94f4... 8bc9c52... M  app/views/orders/new.html.erb
```

Comment: A combination of `sort` and `uniq` might help you, depending on how many of those columns you really need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An exact answer probably depends on your end goal, but would something like this do?

```
git diff --raw 7c8358e HEAD    # specify HEAD in case of local modifications
```

Or if all you really care about is the file list:

```
git diff --name-status 7c8358e HEAD
```

You're not going to get commit messages this way, like you do from whatchanged. I'm not sure I can think of any really consistent way to get both the commit list and the files changed without listing duplicates. You could get the commit messages separately, of course:

```
git log --oneline 7c8358e..    # or --pretty=%s or whatever format you want
```